# Mail a custom excel as attachment

Tags: apex, reporting, apex-email-service

I would like to create a custom table every day and send it as attachment with an excel file then send it to a set of user or mail address. 
The problem is how can I automate the creation of the excel and the email part.

I saw the old answer for the custom report, but is not good to me, I have just a page were I plot my data (plus another one where I can download it which I want to replace with the mail every day)

Here the screen of the page and the excel:

[image]

[image: excel]

Comment: I'm not affiliated with conga, but that sounds a lot like what their conga composer product is designed for. It may not come out of the box with a method to automate the generation (thats an extra fee), but it would be able to create an excel sheet based on a template and send it via email. [Conga Composer Website](https://getconga.com/solutions/documents/composer/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying to do it without external services because is the only case which I need help. I don't think is worth it a membership just for this. By the way I'll keep this as last resort just in case.